# Synchronous call in vertx

Tags: vert.x

We try to refactor our project from servlet to vertx3.x. And we want to reuse the `DAO` layer which take responsibility for query data:

```
interace Adapter {
    List<Feature> query(String layer);
}

class DataBaseAdapter implements Adapter {

}

class FileAdapter implements Adapter {

}

class HttpVertx extends AbstractVertx {
    void start() {
        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.route().handler((h->{
            List<Feature> r=new ArrayList();
            String[] layers=getLayerFromRequest(h.request());
            layers.forEach(l->{
                h.vertx().executeBlocking(future->{
                    future.complete(getAdapter(l).query(l));
                },false,res->{
                    List<Feature> data=res.result();
                    r.addAll(data);
                    //now how can I know that the loop have ended, and I can send the `r` to the client?
                });
            });

        }));
        server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
    }

    Adapter getAdapter(String layer){
        //return database or file adapter accordingly
        return null;
    }
}
```

As shown, the original `adapter` querying are all block operation, once I execute them in a loop, I do not know when they have all done.

Furthermore, I am not sure if it is necessary to refactor the `DatabaseAdapter` using the `vertx-jdbc`? If yes, I will have to change the method signature of  `Adapter` interface to synchronous, but the `FileAdapter` does not support that.

What's the proper refactgor solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. try moving the looping logic into the `executeBlocking` block and changing the handler type to `Handler<List<Feature>>`
2. no, it's not absolutely necessary as wrapping these calls in `executeBlocking` is already doing the expensive work of your database interactions against the Verticle's worker pool.

Comment: Why I call the `executeBlocking` inside the loop is that I want the database call for each layer can be executed at the same time, if moving the loop inside the `executeBlocking`, the database call will be executed one by one.

Answer (score 0):

First, **don't use `executeBlocking()`**. It breaks the entire idea of Vert.x
Second, I would recommend to rewrite your DAO to return `Future`. It will require some work, but the work will be pretty straightforward.

On the high level, it should look something like this:

```
// Use map(), as it returns value
List<Future> futures = layers.map((l) -> {
   return getAdapter(l).query(l);
});

CompositeFuture.all(futures).setHandler((r) -> {
   if (r.succeeded()) {
    // Continue here
   }
});
```

Comment: But `executeBlocking` will be executed at the worker thread. Is there any difference between the `executeBlocking` and your solution?

Comment: The difference is that size of your worker thread pool is also quite limited. Do that, and you'll back in the Servlet world, without any benefits.